# Kingswaysoft Salesforce Upsert Upsert External Id Field

Tags: ssis, salesforce, kingswaysoft

I have a simply SSIS package that creates Salesforce data from an Excel spreadsheet. I want to convert the package to use Upserts, but I get an error after selecting the Upsert function. It says

> Error: Upsert ExternalId Field was not provided.

This is happening on all entities, and I've tried several different input data types, but no matter what I do the "Upsert External ID Field" dropdown is blank. How can I get past this so that I can use Upserts?

Answer (score 0):

For the Upsert function to work, you need to designate one of the fields to be used as the External ID field. This is done within Salesforce as shown below. 
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is a FeedItem object and I don't see anyway to set a field as upsert on that object. May just not be possible.

Comment: We just added the support to allows you to use ID field to perform an Upsert action to Salesforce, can you please reach out to us through our [official Support Channel](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us) so that we can send you the temporary build?